# Query DB with the little things, or store some "bigger chunks" of results and filter them in code?

Tags: c#, .net, database, performance

I'm working on an application that imports video files and lets the user browse them and filter them based on various conditions. By **importing** I mean creating instances of my `VideoFile` model class and storing them in a DB table. Once hundreds of files are there, the user wants to browse them.

Now, the first choice they have in the UI is to select a `DateRecorded`, which calls a `GetFilesByDate(Date date)` method on my data access class. This method will query the SQL database, asking only for files with the given date.

On top of that, I need to filter files by, let's say, `FrameRate`, `Resolution` or `UserRating`. This would place additional criteria on the files already filtered by their date. I'm deciding which road to take:

1. Only query the DB for a new set of files when the desired `DateRecorded` changes. Handle all subsequent filtering manually in C# code, by iterating over the stored collection of `_filesForSelectedDay` and testing them against current additional rules.
2. Query the DB each time any little filter changes, asking for a smaller and very specific set of files more often.

Which one would you choose, or even better, any thoughts on pros and cons of either of those?

Some additional points:

- A query in `GetFilesByDate` is expected to return *tens* of items, so it's not very expensive to store the result in a collection always sitting in memory.
- Later down the road I might want to select files not just for a specific day, but let's say for the entire month. This may give hundreds or thousands of items. This actually makes me lean towards option two.
- The data access layer is not yet implemented. I just have a dummy class implementing the required interface, but storing the data in a in-memory collection instead of working with any kind of DB.
- Once I'm there, I'll almost certainly use SQLite and store the database in a local file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd always go the DB every time until it proves impractical.  If it's a small amount of data then the overhead should also be small.  When it gets larger then the DB comes into its own.  It's unlikely you will be able to write code better than the DB although the round trip can cost.  Using the DB your data will always be consistent and up to date.

If you find you are hitting the BD too hard then you can try caching your data and working out if you already have some or all of the data being requested to save time.  However then you have aging and consistency problems to deal with.  You also then have servers with memory stuffed full of data that could be used for other things!

Basically, until it becomes an issue, just use the DB and use your energy on the actual problems you encounter, not the maybes.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already gotten a bunch of data to begin with, there's no need to query the db again for a subset of *that* set. Just store it in an object which you can query on refinement of the search query by the user.